# A general solution to $\min_{v\in L^2(0,1)} \|v-w\|^2_{L(0,1)}$ s.t. $v(x) \geq 0 $ almost everywhere

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

As the title states, I need to find a solution to

$$\min_{v\in L^2(0,1)} \|v-w\|^2_{L(0,1)}$$

s.t. $v(x) \geq 0  $ almost everywhere,

where  $w \in L^2(0,1)$ is given.

$L^2(0,1)$ is the lebesgue space

I know that there is a solution if $v$ was bounded to a convex and bounded subset of $L^2(0,1)$ and there were no additional constraints.

So my idea was to somehow put the constraint $v(x) \geq 0$ into the set over which we minimize since $ L^2(0,1)$ is allready a convex set(right?). However I do not really seem to get far with this.

Comment: Why not trying to find explicitely the solution in term of $w$ ?

Comment: Could you elaborate this idea a little bit?

Comment: I changed \underset{v\in L^2({0,1})}{\mathrm{min}} to \min_{v\in L^2(0,1)}. That is standard usage. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**

$$||v-w||^{2}_{L^2(0,1)}=\int_{\{x \in(0,1),w(x) \ge 0 \}} |v(x)-w(x)|^2dx+\int_{\{x \in(0,1),w(x) < 0 \}} |v(x)-w(x)|^2dx.$$

How would you chose $v$ on $\{x \in(0,1),w(x) \ge 0 \}$ such that $\int_{\{x \in(0,1),w(x) \ge 0 \}} |v(x)-w(x)|^2dx$ is minimal ? And what about the other set ?

Comment: For the first set $v$ would just be $w$ and for the other $0$, right? So the solution would just be $max(u,0)$ , where $u$ would be the solution to the minimization problem without the constraints.